# How to declaratively pre-install specific queues for self host NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NSB 4.6.4.  I know I could use the following code in my self host process to create necessary queues and Raven DB documents specifically for my configuration:

```
Configure.With()
.UnicastBus()
.CreateBus()
.Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install());
```

But is there any way to get these pre-installed before my process is running, separately in a declarative way (not running through code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to do that, take a look in the [managing NserviceBus using PowerShell article](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/managing-nservicebus-using-powershell)

Comment: I need to pre-install a specific end point and its queues in MSMQ, per app.config in my self host process.  Can you please point me to the specific PS command to do so?  I have tried "Install-NServiceBusMSMQ", but that does nothing.

Comment: @GaryZhang, you could use [plain PS to create your queues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajay/archive/2010/03/18/powershell-script-to-create-an-msmq.aspx). Make sure they are created as transactional queues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sean's last comment, here is the powershell script I use:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPArtialName("System.Messaging")
$msmq = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]
$userName = "Users"
$baseQueueName = ".\private$\myQueueName"
$mainQueue = $baseQueueName
$retryQueue = $baseQueueName + ".retries"
$timeoutQueue = $baseQueueName + ".timeouts"
$timeOutDispatcherQueue = $baseQueueName + ".timeoutsDispatcher"
$nameArray = $mainQueue, $retryQueue, $timeoutQueue, $timeoutDispatcherQueue
for ($i=0; $i -lt $nameArray.length; $i++) 
{ 
If ($msmq::Exists($nameArray[$i]))
{
Echo ($nameArray[$i] + " queue already exists . . . skipping.")
}
else
{
Echo ("Creating queue '" + $nameArray[$i] + "'.")
# second argument of 1 indicates Transactional Queue
$qObject = $msmq::Create($nameArray[$i], 1) 
}

Echo ("Adding Permissions for '" + $userName + "' to queue '" + $nameArray[$i] + ".")

$q2 = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $nameArray[$i]
$q2.SetPermissions($userName, 
[System.Messaging.MessageQueueAccessRights]::FullControl, 
[System.Messaging.AccessControlEntryType]::Set) 
}
```